# how do i extract the multiple pattern in a column value and put it in new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-re

I am unexperienced in coding, need help in this simple code.

I can’t split Index, expirydate, strike and opt type.

I am stuck in splitting expiry date.

```
**Sample 1**
data = ["NIFTY2431322000PE", "NIFTY2441522000PE"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'details': data})

# Regular expression pattern to match the desired format
pattern = r'([A-Z]+)(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{5})([A-Z]+)'
df[['Instrument', 'Year', 'month', 'Date', 'strike', 'CEorPE']] = df['details'].str.extract(pattern)
```

```
RESULT
             details Instrument Year month Date strike CEorPE
0  NIFTY2431322000PE      NIFTY   24     3   13  22000     PE
1  NIFTY2441522000PE      NIFTY   24     4   15  22000     PE
```

```
SAMPLE 2
data = ["NIFTY24MAR22000PE", "NIFTY24DEC22000PE"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'details': data})

pattern = r'([A-Z]+)(\d{2})([A-Z]+)(\d{5})([A-Z]+)'
df[['Instrument', 'Year','month', 'strike', 'CEorPE']] = df['details'].str.extract(pattern)
df['date'] = '30'
```

```
Result
             details Instrument Year month strike CEorPE date
0  NIFTY24MAR22000PE      NIFTY   24   MAR  22000     PE   30
1  NIFTY24DEC22000PE      NIFTY   24   DEC  22000     PE   30
```

I can’t figure out how to run on dataframe which have multiple variation

```
data = ["NIFTY2431322000PE", "NIFTY24DEC22000PE"]
```

If possible I want expiry date in 1 column..

thank you in advance

Comment: what do you want to split to what desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
pattern = r'([A-Z]+)(\d{2})(\d{1}|[A-Z]+)(\d{2})?(\d{5})([A-Z]+)'
df[['Instrument', 'Year', 'month', 'date', 'strike', 'CEorPE']
  ] =  df['details'].str.extract(pattern).fillna({'date': 30})
```

Same with named capturing groups:

```
pattern = r'(?P<Instrument>[A-Z]+)(?P<Year>\d{2})(?P<month>\d{1}|[A-Z]+)(?P<date>\d{2})?(?P<strike>\d{5})(?P<CEorPE>[A-Z]+)'
df[['Instrument', 'Year', 'month', 'date', 'strike', 'CEorPE']] =  df['details'].str.extract(pattern).fillna({'date': 30})
```

Output:

```
             details Instrument Year month date strike CEorPE
0  NIFTY2431322000PE      NIFTY   24     3   13  22000     PE
1  NIFTY24DEC22000PE      NIFTY   24   DEC   30  22000     PE
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvHWy7/1)

Comment: Is it correct to extract only one number from month for actual dataset? I don't think it's a problem with the answer, but I think the questioner should provide the exact logic for the related processing.

Comment: @PandaKim yes that's true, very valid point! I thought the same but forgot to mention it.

Comment: i did not think of that.. thanks for the input..
i'll check my code again..
if you guyz found the answer than do share it..

add NIFTY24121322000PE to the dataframe and try spliting again

Comment: @Panda kim replace (?P<month>\d{1}|[A-Z]+) with (?P<month>\d{1,2}|[A-Z]+)

i hope i am right..

Comment: @Amingohusk you might want to anchor to the end of string with `$` in the end of the regex